# How to diagonalise this pentadiagonal pseudo-Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

How can one diagonalise this N-by-N pentadiagonal matrix (where $r$ is some real constant)?

$$ \tiny
\begin{pmatrix}
  r^2 +r &       -2r -1 &            1 & & & & & & \\
-2r^2 -r &   r^2 +4r +1 &       -2r -2 &            1 &   & & & & \\
  r^2    & -2r^2 -2r    &   r^2 +4r +1 &      -2r  -2 & 1 & & & & \\
         &   r^2        & -2r^2 -2r    &   r^2 +4r +1 & -2r -2    & 1 & & &  \\
         &              &   r^2        & -2r^2 -2r    & r^2 +4r +1 & -2r -2 & 1 & &  \\
 \\
 & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \ddots &  \\
 \\
 & & & & r^2 & -2r^2 -2r  &   r^2 +4r +1 &      -2r -2 &   1 \\
 & & & &     &   r^2      & -2r^2 -2r    &  r^2 +4r +1 & r-2 \\
 & & & &     &            &   r^2        & -r^2 -2r    & r+1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}
$$

Re-written for clarity

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 h   &  e  &  1  &     &     &     &   &   \\
 g   &  a  &  b  &  1  &     &     &   &   \\
r^2  &  c  &  a  &  b  &  1  &     &   &   \\
     & r^2 &  c  &  a  &  b  &  1  &   &   \\
     &     & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &  \\
     &     &     & r^2 &  c  &  a  & b & 1 \\
     &     &     &     & r^2 &  c  & a & k \\
     &     &     &     &     & r^2 & l & m \\
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}
$$

where $a=r^2+4r+1$, $b=-2r-1$, $c=-2r^2-2r$, $h=r^2+r$, $e=-2r-1$, $g=-2r^2-1$, $k=r-2$, $l=-r^2-2r$ and $m=r+1$.

I have been ttempting to solve it by hand but I cannot yet find a workable method - it does seem however that some recursive method must exist as it does for Toeplitz matrices.

This problem arose by studying the system
$$
\begin{matrix}
& \frac{df_1}{dt} = -rf_1+f_2 \\
& \vdots \\
& \frac{df_n}{dt} = rf_{n-1}-(r+1)f_n+f_{n+1} \\
& \vdots \\
& \frac{df_N}{dt} = rf_{N-1}-f_N
\end{matrix}
$$
and setting $\frac{d^{2}f_n}{dt^2} = 0$ for all $n$.

Help will be greatly appreciated.